# Handling the response from Angular 5 Http call

Tags: javascript, angular

```
getItems() {
    this.fetchItemsService.fetchItems(this.url, this.searchTex).subscribe((res) => {
        this.repos = res['items'];
    })
}
```

Above code is working fine but initially I tried as follow

```
getItems() {
    this.fetchItemsService.fetchItems(this.url, this.searchText).subscribe((res) => {
       this.items= res.items;
   })
}
```

This is throwing an error **Items** is not defined on **res**

> **res** is an object

Why is it like that?

Comment: Please give a proper [mcve]. I'd guess you need better typing somewhere.

Comment: (res:any) not (res)

Comment: console.log(res) just to see what it is. then it will be easy to answer

Comment: @Nour it would be better to be more specific than `any` if at all possible; otherwise you might as well not be using TS.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You are right but what i meant is he should specify the type of the response

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare that would be at *run* time, where the OP is saying it *does* have that property (hence the first version works). The error is presumably at *compile* time, where `tsc` doesn't know that. So logging won't be any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer [this link](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response) to know, why you can't use `res.data` instead of `res['data']`.

You can't write `res.data` because TypeScript correctly complains that the `res` object from the service does not have a `data` property.

The `HttpClient.get()` method parsed the JSON server response into the anonymous Object type. It doesn't know what the shape of that object is.

You can tell `HttpClient` the type of the response to make consuming the output easier and more obvious.